# Why connect-mongo creates new session for every request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, express, passport.js

I have two nodejs servers (web-server, socket-server), that are connected to each other by socket.io. On web-service I use express.js and passport.js as authentication middleware.

This is my web-server config:

```
var express = require('express'),
    mongo = require('mongodb'),
    io = require('socket.io'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        store: new MongoStore({
          db: 'MyDatabase'
        })
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/htdocs'));
});
```

**When I use connect-mongo, it creates a new session for each http-request.**

This element creates with log in request:

```
{
  "_id" : "UCnXade6Bk6ofOZ+jiEgzyH8",
  "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":31536000000,\"expires\":\"2014-03-07T13:07:45.703Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{\"user\":\"50cae08806e31ea2e5634e3f\"}}",
  "expires" : new Date("7.3.2014 19:07:45")
}
```

And this element creates each time, when I press F5, or take socket.

```
{
  "_id" : "JhypbYFtj1CGOK/ylMhG8+Yk",
  "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{}}",
  "expires" : new Date("21.3.2013 19:03:38")
}
```

When web-server takes socket connection, connect-mongo creates new session. There are about 50 new documents per minute.

What could be the reason?

**UPDATE**

In the case of updating the page, helped tip to add `app.use(express.favicon())`.

With sockets question is still actual.

My socket-server code

```
function sendPortalJSON (portal_id, data, _event) {
    https.get({
        host : ....,
        port : ....,
        path : "/" + _event + "?data=" + encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify (data))
    }).on('error', function (err) {

    });
}
...
sendPortalJSON(1, agent_data[i].d, "cpu-details");
```

And on web-server:

```
app.get('/cpu-details', function (req, res) { });
```

Answer (score 2):

First, try moving the static middleware to before the session middleware. Also, some browsers handle requests for `/favicon.ico` a bit funky, so try using `express.favicon()` to see if it solves your problem.

So something like this:

```
...
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/htdocs'));
app.use(express.session({...});
...
```

Comment: Awesome! When I used `express.favicon()`, all was well when I press F5. But, when I started my socket.io server, connect-mongo still continues create new documents.

I added some code of my socket-server.

Comment: Make sure to place any routes or middleware that should not be handled by passport and/or the sessions middlewares *before* those middlewares. Just curious, but is there a reason that you're using a separate socket.io server? You can mix socket.io and Express together in one server app.

Comment: I incorrectly said. Я have two nodejs servers, and connection is made between them by socket.io.